# finding activity in which desired layout found in android

Tags: android, layout

Is there any short cut to find activity in which desired xml layout is found. I have many activities, now I want to find a xml Layout from the activities where it is used, I am trying to find that xml Layout one by one from activities. but it's long way. kindly suggest me any suitable solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Why can't you just do a text search for the layout name?

Comment: @ Simon I want to find xml layout from the Package. Package has many Activities . I dont't want to find layout by opening each activity of package and press Ctrl+f.